# Setting up Spark on IntelliJ for contributing to Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have lot a lot of time trying to set up spark on Intellij on my local machine.

Goal : To run `SparkPi.scala` with out any errors.

Steps Taken:

```
git clone `https://github.com/apache/spark`
Import the project to Intellij as a Maven Project
build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
navigate to examples folder modify pom.xml (change occurrences of provided , test -> compile)
Open SparkPi.scala and add `.master("local[4]")` to Spark Session
Right click and run SparkPi
```

Error I am faced with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/MapMaker
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:822)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.MapMaker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `rebuild` the project under Intellij. Sad but true: IJ is unable to simply reuse the `maven` built infrastructure.

However it does use *part* of the command line `mvn` structure: you do need to run the `mvn` first.

As for the `google MapMaker` class: it means the dependencies are not being downloaded properly and not available. This should be resolved after the full rebuild.

Comment: How can i rebuild? An example would be helpful.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan  I am simply referring to the `Project | Rebuild` option from Main Menu.